# Read last N lines from a dat file

Tags: matlab

I have a large file and I would like to read last N lines and save it to an array.

```
...
0000060000 -8.87581605E-01 +8.75699302E-01 +9.06740431E+00                                            
0000060000 +6.19341761E-01 +4.28899944E-01 +5.01890155E+00                                            
0000060000 +1.68698000E+00 +9.26797393E-01 +5.91791531E+00                                            
0000060000 -2.90325069E+00 -1.38036121E+00 +5.37741815E+00                                            
0000060000 -1.78177889E+00 +1.18435200E-01 +3.77356637E+00
```

How to achieve this without loading the entire file?

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 methods:

```
Filename='Myfile.csv';
N=5;

%Read file
fid=fopen(Filename,'r');
text=fread(fid,'*char')';
fclose(fid);

%Preprocess
text(char(13))=[]; %remove cr, to make things clean

%Method 1
idxs=find(text==char(10),N+1,'last'); %line ending position 
Result1=text( idxs(1)+1:idxs(end) )

%Method 2
AllRows=regexp(text,char(10),'split')';
Result2=AllRows(end-N:end)
```

You need to know about your file structure to decide what to do about the last line.